# How to throttle C# workload?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with a file watcher. It only needs to perform the action after no more events have fires for like 10 seconds.

For these types of problems I use a throttle function in JavaScript and I was wondering if C# can do something similar:

```
var t = null;
function throttleAction(fn){
    if(t != null){
        window.clearTimeout(t);
    }
    t = window.setTimeout(function(){
        t = null;
        fn();
    }, 10000);  
}
```

How would I implement something like this in C#?

Comment: try c# timer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this a weird question?

Comment: I would assume you were downloaded because you could have found the result very easily just by googling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Set the Interval property to your chosen interval, write your worker function and then pass it as a delegate to the [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Finally, Start the timer.